SwiftUI Map overriding appearance of ToolBar / NavigationBar?
When adding a Map using the MapKit this changes the appearance of the TabBar appearance, specifically gives the toolbar a translucent background with a shadow; the default iOS style.
I have tried adding the following modifier to the Map
.toolbarBackground(Color("White"), for: .navigationBar)

But the navigation toolbar still has a shadow, and the TabBar has the default translucent background colour with shadow.
Root
init() {
    // this is not the same as manipulating the proxy directly
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    
    // this overrides everything you have set up earlier.
    appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
    
    appearance.shadowColor = .clear
    
    //In the following two lines you make sure that you apply the style for good
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
    
    
    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
    UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()
    
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    UIToolbar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    UIToolbar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    UIToolbar.appearance().setShadowImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: .any)
}

struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ContentView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Menu", systemImage: "list.dash")
                }
        }
    }
}

The Tabbar has a solid white colour with no shadow, as well as navigation bars.
Content View
struct ContentView: View {

@State var position = MapCameraPosition.region(
    MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.510357, longitude: -0.116773),
        latitudinalMeters: 500, longitudinalMeters: 500)
)

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack() {
            NavigationLink(destination: MapView(position: $position)) {
              Text("Hello, World!")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Content")
    }
}

MapView
struct MapView: View {
    @Binding var position:  MapCameraPosition

    var body: some View {
        Map(position: $position)
            .mapControlVisibility(.hidden)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
            .allowsHitTesting(false)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(height: 414)
            .clipped()
    }
}

I have looked through the documentation but could not find anything. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/map

Note, NavigationView is deprecated, use NavigationStack. There are also newer versions of Map calls, see: Map

@workingdogsupportUkraine thanks for the reply, I've updated answer, still facing the issue

Please show what do you need and what do you get with images to clarify

1. Applying Solid Color
To have a solid color on a bar, you must ensure it is both colored AND visible using:
.toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .tabBar)
.toolbarBackground(.white, for: .tabBar)

Also, note that the configuration MUST be applied INSIDE the Navigation or Tab view and must NOT on themselves!
For example, I have applied them on the Map deep inside:

2. Removing the shadow ('aka' hairline)
Unfortunately, there is no straight way in Swiftui to hide those shadows. but you can hide both the background color AND the shadow at the same time by passing hidden:
.toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .tabBar)
.toolbarBackground(.white, for: .tabBar)


3. Add colors to behind invisible bars
You can add a background color ignoring all safe-area and subtract the safe-area to make it appear as the background of bars:
ZStack {
    Color(.red).ignoresSafeArea()
    Rectangle().blendMode(.destinationOut)
}
.compositingGroup()


✅ Conclusion
Of course you can use the .white color combined with the method 3 to achieve what you originally asked:


PS: Get rid of that init method you write entirely!
PS: Don't forget to check your needs for the dark mode! You can simply use the method 2 and just clip the contents if you need the bars to be matched with the current color scheme (light/dark)

Thank you so much for your reply, on MapView the TabBar and NavigationBar displays correct, however when I go back to ContentView the ToolBars actually go back to translucent with shadow. So its Content View with White > MapView with White > Content View Translucent

I think you are changing the appearance somewhere else. Here is what I see with no issues.

Rewarded! I had to wait for x amount of time before rewarding. Thank you!! This was such a pain

a follow up, it appears the modifier changes the navigation font set in init, is there any way of preventing this? or changing the font again

Sorry but I didn't understand. By the way, comments is not a good place to discuss technicals. Please open a new question with proper detail and minimum reproducible code so that me and the community can contribute

Sure thing, I posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78480945/toolbarbackground-modifier-changes-font-of-navigation-bar-swiftui
