toolbarBackground modifier changes title attributes of UINavigationBar.appearance - SwiftUI
I change the font of the navigation bar like so,
init() {
    // Initialise Firebase
    //FirebaseApp.configure()

    // this is not the same as manipulating the proxy directly
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    
    // this overrides everything you have set up earlier.
    appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
    
    // this only applies to big titles
    appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [
        .font : UIFont(name: "Poppins", size: 38)!,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor(named: "Dark")!
    ]
    // this only applies to small titles
    appearance.titleTextAttributes = [
        .font : UIFont(name: "Poppins", size: 20)!,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor(named: "Dark")!
    ]
    
    let back = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
    back.normal.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "arrow.left")
    back.normal.titleTextAttributes = [
        .font : UIFont(name: "Poppins", size: 20)!,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor(named: "Dark")!
    ]
    
    appearance.backButtonAppearance = back
    appearance.shadowColor = .clear
    
    #if !targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "White")
    #endif

    //In the following two lines you make sure that you apply the style for good
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
    
    // This property is not present on the UINavigationBarAppearance
    // object for some reason and you have to leave it til the end
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(named: "Black")
    UINavigationBar.appearance().prefersLargeTitles = true
    UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear

    
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    UIToolbar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "White")
    UIToolbar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    
 }

When adding the following modifiers to a view, specifically to Map as SwiftUI Map overrides the toolbar appearances for TabBar and NavigationBar.
.toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .tabBar
.toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)

This then changes changes title attributes of UINavigationBar.appearance and uses the default iOS appearance.
I have tried using [SwiftUI-Introspect][1] to modify the navigation bar like so, however this did not work.
.introspect(
    .navigationView(style: .stack),
    on: .iOS(.v13, .v14, .v15, .v16, .v17), .tvOS(.v13, .v14, .v15, .v16, .v17)
) { navigationController in
    navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    
    let navbarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    navbarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    navbarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    navbarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    
    navbarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [
        .font : UIFont(name: "Poppins", size: 38)!,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor(named: "Dark")!
    ]
    // this only applies to small titles
    navbarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [
        .font : UIFont(name: "Poppins", size: 20)!,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor(named: "Dark")!
    ]
    
    navbarAppearance.shadowColor = .clear
    navbarAppearance.shadowImage = UIImage()

    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navbarAppearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = navbarAppearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navbarAppearance
    
}

It changes the font back to default. Why is this and how can I change the font/prevent this from happening?
This is a follow up from a prev question on why Map overrides the toolbar appearance. The workaround was using the Toolbar modifier.
Full code:
import SwiftUI
import MapKit


struct RootController: View {
    init() {
        // Initialise Firebase
        //FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        // this is not the same as manipulating the proxy directly
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        
        // this overrides everything you have set up earlier.
        appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
        
        // this only applies to big titles
        appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [
            .font : UIFont(name: "Times", size: 38)!,
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red
        ]
        // this only applies to small titles
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [
            .font : UIFont(name: "Times", size: 20)!,
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red
        ]
        
        let back = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
        back.normal.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "arrow.left")
        back.normal.titleTextAttributes = [
            .font : UIFont(name: "Times", size: 20)!,
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red
        ]
        
        appearance.backButtonAppearance = back
        appearance.shadowColor = .clear
        
#if !targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
#endif
        
        //In the following two lines you make sure that you apply the style for good
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        
        // This property is not present on the UINavigationBarAppearance
        // object for some reason and you have to leave it til the end
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.black
        UINavigationBar.appearance().prefersLargeTitles = true
        UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
        UIToolbar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        UIToolbar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
        
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ContentView()
            .tabItem {
                Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
            }

            NavigationStack {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "globe")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundStyle(.tint)
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Account", systemImage: "person")
            }
        }
        .background(Color.white) // Set tab view background explicitly
    }
}

#Preview {
    RootController()
}


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        @State var position = MapCameraPosition.region(
            MKCoordinateRegion(
                center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.510357, longitude: -0.116773),
                latitudinalMeters: 500, longitudinalMeters: 500)
        )
        
        NavigationStack() {
            ScrollView() {
                NavigationLink(destination: MapView(position: $position)) {
                    Text("See Map")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                        .padding(.top, 400)
                        .padding(.bottom, 600)
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .navigationTitle("Content")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Content")
        
    }
}

struct MapView: View {
    @Binding var position:  MapCameraPosition
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack() {
            ZStack() {
                Color(.white).ignoresSafeArea()
                Rectangle().blendMode(.destinationOut)
            }
            .compositingGroup()
            
            Map(position: $position)
                .mapControlVisibility(.hidden)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .frame(height: 414)
                .clipped()
                .padding()
//                .toolbarBackground(.white, for: .navigationBar)

        }
        .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
        .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
        .navigationTitle("Map")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
    }
}


Another reason not to mix UIKit with SwiftUI. If you set the navigation bar's appearance with UIKit APIs, don't expect SwiftUI modifiers that modify the navigation bar to happily work alongside it. Pick one or the other. Or use SwiftUI Introspect

See also Change NavigationStack title font, tint, and background in SwiftUI

Please provide a minimum working project somewhere like GitHub and link it here so anyone can see the issue and probably come with a workaround

Done, just create a new project and copy and paste to ContentView. Toolbar modifiers override navigation title

I can' see the font change even without those 2 lines
